# Indices of resampled array in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.x, scipy

I have two 1D-array, of the same length, containing a time series and value series, for example

```
t = linspace(0, 5, 5) # [0, 1.25, 2.5, 3.75, 5]
x = array(range(10, 25)) # [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

I have to resample the x array using different sampling points in time, (with same start and end point, but could have any number of elements) for example

```
r = linspace(0, 5, 4) # [ 0, 1.667, 3.333, 5]
x2 = resample(t, x, r) # [10, 11, 12, 14]
```

That is, each time point of r is placed between two time points of t, and I'd like to find the index of the lower point of the two in t. From an array of indexes, is then possible to get the relative points of x.

I'd like a vector-based solution, without loops, possibly using scipy's operators.
Better if using scipy's functions.

EDIT: here's a code that do what I need, but a shorter, faster and vector-based solution would be better. I could not find one (till trying though).

```
def resample(t, r):
    i, j, k = 0, 1, 0
    s = []
    while j < len(t):
        if t[i] <= r[k] < t[j]:
            s.append(i)
            k += 1
        else:
            i += 1
            j += 1
    s.append(len(t) - 1)
    return array(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second of the following two little functions can get what you want done:

```
def resample_up(t, x, r) :
    return x[np.argmax(r[:, None] <= t, axis=1)]

def resample_down(t, x, r) :
    return x[::-1][np.argmax(r[:, None] >= t[::-1], axis=1)]

>>> resample_up(t, x, r)
array([10, 12, 13, 14])
>>> resample_down(t, x, r)
array([10, 11, 12, 14])
```

If you find it hard to figure out what's going on, the following may help:

```
>>> r[:, None] <= t
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
>>> r[:, None] >= t[::-1]
array([[False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

and then `np.argmax` is returning the index of the first occurrence of `True` in every row.

**EDIT** IT is hard to get it shorter than a single line of code, but for large arrays performance will suffer, because the index finding never breaks out early of loops. So for very large arrays, scanning through the array with python loops may turn out to be faster. For smaller ones it does not:

```
In [2]: %timeit resample_up(t, x, r)
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.32 us per loop

In [3]: %timeit resample_down(t, x, r)
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.44 us per loop

In [4]: %timeit resample(t, x, r) # modified version of the OP's taking also x
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.7 us per loop
```

Comment: Nice, it uses syntax I did not know for indexing arrays!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `interp1d` function in `scipy.interpolate`, specifying the `kind` argument to be `zero`. Using your arrays:

```
>>> from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
>>> f = interp1d(t,x,kind="zero")
>>> f(r)
array((10, 11, 12, 13))
```

Note that the last element in the "resampled" array is 13, not 14 as you requested in the question, but `f(5.001) = 14` (*). The interpolating function is discontinuous whenever the "resampled" array matches one of the points in the original array.

(*) You need to specify the keyword argument `bounds_error=False` in the `interp1d` call if you want to resample outside the range of `t`.

Comment: Nice, and thanks for your addition with details, but the last point is required to coincide. Sure, it's possible to artificially introduce another one, but I believe that it could lead to (very small) errors in sampling.

Answer (score 1):

[numpy.interp](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) is a fast simple piecewise-linear interpolator:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0, 5, 5)  # [0, 1.25, 2.5, 3.75, 5]
x = np.array(range(10, 15))  # [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
r = np.linspace(0, 5, 4)  # [ 0, 1.667, 3.333, 5]

print "np.interp:", np.interp( r, t, x )
    # [ 10.    11.33  12.67  14.  ]
xint = np.arange( len(t) )
print "r to int:", np.interp( r, t, xint ).astype(int)
    # [0 1 2 4]
```